# Deviance plot of Training and Testing Data

Tags: r

I built a deviance/splits plot for Decision tree as follows.

```
  data(mtcars)
  cars <- mtcars[,1:4]
  smp_size <- floor(0.75 * nrow(cars))
  set.seed(100)
  train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(LoanData)), size = smp_size)
  train <- LoanData[train_ind, ]
  test <- LoanData[-train_ind, ]

  #Deciscion tree model
  library(tree)
  car_tree <- tree(mpg ~., data=cars, mindev=0.003,mincut=2,minsize = 6)

  #Check deviance
  cv_tree <- cv.tree(car_tree,FUN=prune.tree, K=10)
  plot(cv_tree$size,cv_tree$dev,type="b",xlab="splits",ylab="deviance",
  main="deviance by splits")
```

I want to overlay on this plot the deviance of test data, so as to observe after which split the deviance starts increasing again. Can you kindly let me know how to do the same ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To look at the accuracy of the tree for different depths, the tree needs to be trimmed, and the training and test results predicted, and the accuracy of the training and test results evaluated.

Here is the data, with the training and test subset extracted

```
data(mtcars)
cars <- mtcars
smp_size <- floor(0.75 * nrow(cars))
set.seed(100)
train_ind <- sample(seq_len(nrow(cars)), size = smp_size)
train <- cars[train_ind, ]
test <- cars[-train_ind, ]
```

Here is a helper function to determine the accuracy for training and test data for a given model.  You may want to modify this to include other validation estimates.

```
compare<-function(tr, train, test, dpth, rst=NULL) {
  est.train <- predict(tr,train)
  est.test <- predict(tr,test)
  delta.train = est.train - train$mpg
  delta.test = est.test - test$mpg
  df <- data.frame(cor.train = cor(train$mpg,est.train),
                   cor.test = cor(test$mpg,est.test),
                   sd.train = sd(delta.train),
                   sd.test = sd(delta.test),
                   depth = dpth)
  return(rbind(rst,df))
}
```

Create the tree

```
#Deciscion tree model
library(tree)
car_tree <- tree(mpg ~., data=train, mindev=0.003,mincut=2,minsize = 6)
```

Print the tree, determine the depth (3), and the deepest splitting nodes (4:7)

```
car_tree
# Depth is 3 and the 3rd level nodes are 4:7
```

Get the results for the depth of 3

```
rslts<-compare(car_tree,train,test,3)
```

Now trim the tree, and print it.  Notice the next depth is 2, and the deepest nodes are 2:3

```
(car_tree_sn_1 <- snip.tree(car_tree,c(4:7)))
# Depth is 2 and the 2nd level nodes are 2:3
```

Get the results for the depth of 2

```
rslts<-compare(car_tree_sn_1,train,test,2,rslts)
```

Now trim the tree, and print it.  Notice the next depth is 1, and there are no split node

```
(car_tree_sn_2 <- snip.tree(car_tree,c(2:3)))
# Depth is 1 and there are no split nodes
```

Get the results for the depth of 1

```
rslts<-compare(car_tree_sn_2,train,test,1,rslts)
```

Plot the accuracy estimates

```
plot(rslts$depth,rslts$cor.train,type="b",xlab="splits",ylab="Correlation Coefficient",
     main="Correlation by splits",log="y",ylim=c(.5,1))
lines(rslts$depth,rslts$cor.test,type="b",col="red")
```

[image]

```
plot(rslts$depth,rslts$sd.train,type="b",xlab="splits",ylab="Standard Deviation",
     main="Correlation by splits",log="y",ylim=c(.5,5))
lines(rslts$depth,rslts$sd.test,type="b",col="red")
```

[image]

There are other tree models.  Here is an example of rpart.

```
# Regression Tree Example
data(mtcars)
cars <- mtcars[,1:6]
library(rpart)

# grow tree 
fit <- rpart(mpg ~., data=cars, control=list(minsplit = 1))

printcp(fit) # display the results 
plotcp(fit) # visualize cross-validation results 
summary(fit) # detailed summary of splits

# create additional plots 
par(mfrow=c(1,2)) # two plots on one page 
rsq.rpart(fit) # visualize cross-validation results    

# plot tree 
library(rpart.plot)
prp(fit,extra=101,branch.type=3)
plot(fit, uniform=TRUE, 
     main="Regression Tree for Mileage ")
text(fit, use.n=TRUE, all=TRUE, cex=.8)
```

refs: [cart tree](http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cart.html), [prp plotting](http://www.milbo.org/rpart-plot/prp.pdf), [model prediction](http://www.edii.uclm.es/~useR-2013/Tutorials/kuhn/user_caret_2up.pdf)

Comment: I want to create a cross-validation plot with the 'test' data that I generated in my script. Would that be possible with rpart?

Comment: The above approach is introductory, meant to illustrate a process.  Improvements can be made in the sampling.  Instead of random, select samples based on distribution.  Also K-Fold (caret::createfold) approach is an improvement over the above approach.  Good luck.